# What's wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion

[Why did the Nazis have such a technological advantage in Wolfenstein: The New Order?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246621/why-did-the-nazis-have-such-a-technological-advantage-in-wolfenstein-the-new-or)

I don't quite understand why this question has gotten 2 downvotes shortly after I asked it. According to the help center, plot explanation questions are on topic. And this is plot explanation: why does the history of the game differ from established history? In case it's another reason, I'm perfectly willing to rewrite it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that I have not downvoted your question, and I do not intend to do so. However, I can understand why someone might.

Your question deals with something that is explained normally via the plot. I would assume that people who have played and beaten the game thought this was a "poorly researched" question. I think this enters a grey area where certain players might have a question that they're legitimately curious about before the game bothers to explain something (e.g., "Hey, who is this Darth Vader guy anyway?"). In this kind of situation I think the question itself is perfectly valid (as yours is), and in my opinion an ideal answer would look like this:

> This is explained during the mission "They tell you about the Nazis". The specific reason is: *Some sort of spoiler tagged summary*.

Comment: I have played through the game already, and I can't really remember them explaining this directly. The big issue is that the game starts after the Nazis have basically already won the war: the first mission is a last-ditch effort to maybe win the war, but the missions after that are all set after the war has ended, in a resistance-style storyline. There is not much explanation that i remember as to why the Nazi tech is so much better.

Comment: There's a mission that directly addresses it. I'll answer your question with the relevant info.

Answer (score 13):

Down votes are not close votes.

If your question was off topic, people would be voting to *close* your question. Nobody has.

Instead they have downvoted your question, meaning they believe it is of low quality or not useful. This is an opinion, to which they are entitled, and to which you are entitled to disagree. However, complaining about it is generally considered unbecoming.

Comment: Maybe a better question would be: why do people think my question is "low quality" or "not useful"? I'm willing to rewrite my question, but I have to know what is wrong with it first?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Questions about plot that basically amount to "Explain why the world is the way it is" tend to be poorly received by some users. There are a variety of reasons for this, some of which are better than others. Suffice it to say that there is nothing you could do to rewrite your question that would please them.

Comment: "Complaining" about it is unbecoming, but asking what's wrong with it so it can be improved, like @NateKerkhofs is doing, is the correct and proper course of action. You're absolutely right that some people have a knee-jerk negative reaction to even *mentioning* downvotes, though.